# Allow razor page to be viewed anonymously, but authorize post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I want to allow a page to be viewed by anyone, but only authorized users to be able to submit forms i.e using the post method(s) of a razor page.

However authorize attribute is only applicable at `PageModel` level, I can either make get + post authorizable or both anonymously accessible.

What is the recommended approach in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would only render the form if the user is authenticated:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <partial name="_CommentForm" />
}
```

Then I would perform the same check in the `OnPost` handler before processing the form submission to prevent automated or other nefarious submissions:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if(Modelstate.IsValid)
        {
            // blah blah
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

Or you could post to a different page which is only designed to process the submission and can have the `Authorize` attribute applied to it

Comment: Don't forget to use an anti-forgery token (sorry, I don't use ASP.NET Core yet so I don't know how that works here).

Comment: @howcheng Request Verification is the default for POST requests in Razor Pages: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification.